# How to dispatch an action when a button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```js
//action code 
export const CLEAR_COMPLETED = 'CLEAR_COMPLETED'

export const clearCompleted = () => {
  return{
    type: CLEAR_COMPLETED
  }
}


//reducer code 

case CLEAR_COMPLETED:
      return state.map(todo => {if (todo.completed)
        {return {...todo, show:false}}
          else {return todo}})
```

Problem dispatching action on Todo application in react-redux.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { clearCompleted } from '../actions'


const ClearButton = ({dispatch}) => {
  return(
    <button fluid  onClick={e => {dispatch(clearCompleted())}}>
      Clear Completed
    </button>
  )
}

export default ClearButton
```

Trying to change the store by clicking on Clear Completed Button. Clear Completed Button should remove the completed todos from the store and todo list should be updated. I am trying to call 'clearCompleted' action with Clear Completed Button.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty you're having here is that your component doesn't know anything about the Redux store, and the `dispatch` function will not be in its props. The most basic way you can make `dispatch` available would be this:

```
export default connect()(ClearButton)
```

This will allow you to use `dispatch(clearCompleted())` without messing around further with `mapDispatchToProps`. You'd have to change its definition so it's not a stateless component though.

However, you should probably ask yourself whether a tiny button really needs `connect` at all? You could probably just pass the correct function down from the containing component:

```js
// TodoList.js
class TodoList extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      ...
      <ClearButton clearCompleted={this.props.clearCompleted} />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  // ...
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  clearCompleted: () => dispatch(clearCompleted())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList)
```

Then the function will be in `ClearButton`'s props without it needing to be connected:

```
<button onClick={this.props.clearCompleted}>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by wrapping your component in `connect`.
**connect** accepts two arguments as first call, `mapStateToProps` for mapping your store properties into your component's props and `mapDispatchToProps` for mapping action creators into your component's props. It's also followed by another call to that function with the Component name of yours written in `class syntax`.

> If you insist in using stateless components with `connect`, you can use `compose` utility from `redux`.

```
import React from 'react'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { clearCompleted } from '../actions'

class ClearButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {clearCompleted} = this.props;
    return(
      <button fluid  onClick={clearCompleted}>
        Clear Completed
      </button>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ clearCompleted }, dispatch);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ClearButton);
```